# How to pass data from a class that extends BroadcastReceiver to the activity

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I have two application that one of them have a **class** (not an activity) that extends BroadcastReceiver and listens to a custom broadcast.
The second app is the one that sends the broadcast (an explicit Intent here).
Now I want the broadcast receiver app to send a message back to the app that has triggered it.
I read articles on StackOverFlow but none of them has talked about data passing between two apps.
according to new restriction on Android 8 broadcasts, I need a way to work on Android 8.

Comment: Same way as what you did for current communication

Comment: how can I send data (for example String) to the caller activity from a broadcast receiver class in other application?